# Expressing $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+i)$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} +i)$ in the exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

> Is $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+i)$ equal to $i\frac{-1+e^2}{2e}$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} +i)$ to $\frac{1+e^2}{2e}$?

Trying to answer a test online. Apparently the answer in the question is incorrect or I am not expressing it correctly. Is there a different way to express it with the exponential function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please show your calculations.  Note that in order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  (Look at how I edited the title.)

Comment: Use the formula for $\cos (a + b)$ and $\sin(a+b)$, together with $\cos (ix) = \cosh x$ and $\sin (ix) = i\sinh x$.

Comment: I agree with both answers posted so far. Your first result has the wrong sign, but the second one looks correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the formulas
$$
\cos x = \frac 1 2 (e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) \qquad \sin x = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})
$$

After inserting the values $\frac \pi 2 + i$ into both equations you get the results
$$
\cos \left(\frac \pi 2 + i\right) = \frac 1 2(e^{i\pi/2 + i^2}+e^{-i\pi/2-i^2} ) \\
=\frac 1 2\left(\frac i e + \frac{e}{i}\right) = \frac{i}{2e} - \frac{ie}{2}= i\frac{1-e^2}{2e}
$$
and
$$
\sin\left(\frac \pi 2 + i\right) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\pi/2 + i^2}-e^{-i\pi/2-i^2} ) \\
=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac i e - \frac{e}{i}\right) = \frac{1}{2e} + \frac{e}{2}= \frac{e^2+1}{2e}
$$

using the fact that $e^{i\pi/2}=i$ and $i^2=-1$, thus $1/i=-i$

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth line be $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{i}{e} -ie)$? as $e^{i^2}=\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(\pi/2+i)=-\sin(i)=\frac{-i\sin(i)}{i}=-i\sinh(1)=i\frac{\frac{1}{e}-e}{2}=i\frac{1-e^2}{2e}$$
$$\sin(\pi/2+i)=\cos(i)=\cosh(1)=\frac{e+\frac{1}{e}}{2}=\frac{e^2+1}{2e}$$

Note that:
$$\sinh(x)=-i\sin(ix)$$
and
$$\cosh(x)=\cos(ix)$$